# Quantifier Statement Error?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I'm working on a set of True and False statement that deal with quantifiers, and I suspect there may be an error. The universal set here is rational numbers, so almost everything is on the table. I've triple checked each one with what I could find online, but apparently at least one of these is not the correct answer. Here is my reasoning for each:

1. True as y = 1 - x
2. False as there is no singular value such that when multiplied by any other real number, their product is 1
3. False as it violate the communicative property of addition, which is true for all real numbers
4. False as there is no spot the two equations meet, meaning both equations can never be true at the same time
5. True as for all rational possibilities of $x^2$, there will exist a rational square root.
6. Impossible at there is no rational number that can be squared to make a negative number
7. The statement says that for every two real numbers, there exists a real number that is the average of the two real numbers. This is always true and thus the statement is true.
8. True as for all rational values of x, there exists a singular value of y = 0 to make a product of 0
9. False as there is not a rational value of y that solves the equation for all values of x.
10. False since for negative rational numbers, there is no value of y that could be squared to create it.
11. True as the square root of 2 is a real number.
12. True as for all values of x, there will exist a y such that xy = 1. This is shown with the inverse property of multiplication.

Any hints or help would be greatly appeciated.

[image: Problem in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nr. $7$ is false. It does not say for each pair of real numbers there is a real number that is their average; that would be $\forall x\forall y\exists z\,\left(z=\frac{x+y}2\right)$. It says that for each real number $x$ there is a real number $z$ such that $z=\frac{x+y}2$ for **every** real number $y$, which is clearly false: that says that for each real number $x$ the function

$$f_x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:y\mapsto\frac{x+y}2$$

is a constant function.